# crash toolbar in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, crash, toolbar

When I click on 'Profile' (in the toolbar) it should launch the 'ClickProfile' method but the program crashes. Below are the photos of the xml file and the class method.

XML file:
[image]

Class method:
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any exception/error messages in full, also please copy-paste code into the question itself rather than providing images of your code (it's much easier to read and work with). Also, include all relevant code as well otherwise we will just be guessing at the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.